# Design data structure for simple greedy snake game during interview

Tags: java, c++, data-structures

This is not a practical question, I just want to discuss and learn data structure design here, I heard it's asked by Google during onsite interview. Please advise me how to improve my design, thanks!

At the beginning I wanted to use a deque to store pairs of x,y coordinates for snake's body parts.

```
deque<pair<x, y>> snakeBodyParts;
```

Because it's very easy to push front when snake move - create new coordinate pair as the new head base on old head position and current direction, then pop back to remove the tail. In this way move, eat, check head hit wall are all O(1) operations and easy to implement with deque. But checking if new head position overlap with snakes body will require looping through all body parts' position - O(L) time complexity, L is number of body parts.

To improve it, I thought about putting all coordinates into an unordered_set(C++) or hashset(Java) while still keeping my old deque, it can give me O(1) for checking if head hits body now. But I don't know if it's a good idea because it almost doubles the memory and amount of codes, whenever I add/remove to deque, I need to do it to my hashset.

```
unordered_set<pair<int, int>, pair_hash> bodyPartsSet;
```

I also thought about creating my own structure which is like linkedlist, except it points to previous node:

```
SnakeBodyNode {
    int x;
    int y;
    SnakeBodyNode * prev;
}
```

Then I also need two pointers pointing at head and tail as well as a direction variable.

```
SnakeBodyNode * head;
SnakeBodyNode * tail;
char dir;
```

However I don't see any advantage of this, still need to hash to get O(1) for checking if head hits body..

Is there any flaw in my deque + hash design or any one have better idea to share?

Comment: Last time I wrote a snake game I stored only two coordinates, the position of the head (to move the snake's head forward) and the position of the tail (to move the snakes rear forward by deleting it). I detected *collisions* by the color of the pixels in the cell the snake's head was moving into. It was a faily limited design though tbh. But very *fast* on an `8-bit` micro.

Comment: @Galik  So you saved the position of snakes body by storing a 2D array of entire board and marking if a cell is occupied by snake. Checking if snake gonna hit its body is O(1) then, I think it's pretty good design, no need to use hash table this way, and not too much memory cost unless board is super big.

Comment: How big is your grid? I would prefer to choose the simpler queue implementation. Even if linear search is costly, you only need to walk through a queue of only a few hundred nodes.

Comment: It was even more primative than that, I didn't store a 2D board array, I literally tested the pixel color in the screen buffer, ensuring no other game object used the same color as the snake's body. :)

Comment: @Galik hmm...I don't really see how deleting tail works this way, once you delete it using pointer to tail, how do you update the tail pointer?

Comment: @user1 yeah, I think the snake body usually wouldn't get too long during the game. I don't even feel time complexity should be important for game this simple.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It was so long ago I'm missing something. Maybe the efficiency was that I only needed to draw the head and delete the tail? Maybe I only needed to store the points where the snake changed direction...?

Answer (score 1):

I would just use an unordered_set.  Your concerns are:

- Fast insert of new head - this is O(1) for unordered_set.
- Fast deletion of existing tail - this is O(1) for unordered_set.
- No duplicates (checking that head intersects body) - this is guaranteed
  for unordered_set (it does not allow duplicates).

When inserting a new head, you don't have to do anything special to check that it intersects with the body; you'll get an error if it does.

Comment: Only unordered_set, without any linkedlist like structure? How do you keep track of tail then, once you delete a tail, how do you find next tail to delete?

Comment: Doh! I need to go to bed :)  An unordered_set with your idea of pointing to the previous node would work, no?

Comment: Yeah, it should work, just wonder if there's better design ;)